# How do I test complex relationships in Rails with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Firstly, this question may stray into opinion but I think it's a valuable question to ask. I will give a very specific example for my application which handles absence management and tracking.

An `Account` has many `Users` and a `User` has many `Absences`. The `Account` can create `PublicHolidays` which should be ignored when calculating the number of days that an `Absence` uses.

Example: If a person takes a week off, the days used will be 5. If one of those days is a `PublicHoliday`, the days used would be 4.

I want to implement a method such that when a `PublicHoliday` is created, the days used for any `Absences` created prior to the date of creation and which cross the date of the `PublicHoliday` are recalculated.

My current RSpec test looks like this:

```
it 'triggers a recalculation of absence days on create for absences created before the date of creation of the public holiday' do
  robin = FactoryGirl.create(:robin)
  absence = FactoryGirl.create(:basic_absence, user: robin)
  expect(absence.days_used).to eq(1)
  ph = FactoryGirl.create(:public_holiday, country: "England", account: robin.account)
  expect(absence.reload.days_used).to eq(0)
end
```

In this test, `ph` is the same date as the `absence` so I expect it to calculate one day to start with and then I intend to use an after create callback to recalculate the days used.

Is this the right way to do this test? Is there a more efficient way without creating a number of associated objects?

Comment: My assumption is that for every time a user is absent (including holidays), a new Absence record is created. Since you said days_used = absences - holidays, then wouldnt it be better to put the `days_used` method as part of the User model instead, and not the Absence model? I imagine I would do something like @user.days_used instead of @absence.days_used, unless I misunderstand something

Comment: There is a similar method to days_used on the user model. There are a lot of edge cases around how many days an absence uses and the logic is quite complex so I don't want to move it.

Comment: Aside from explicitly specifying the date as the following `ph = FactoryGirl.create(:public_holiday, country: "England", account: robin.account, created_at: absence.created_at)` (also makes sure that at midnight, the test will not fail), I think the test is sound.

Comment: I'd write this as two tests, not because there's anything wrong with multiple expectations in a single test in general, but because your two expectations are on different actions. But your general strategy seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly - it's good practice to use `let`s instead of local variables, and secondly - split your tests so each test tests just one thing. Thirdly: anything that sets up a context for tests should be put into a context-block (even if there's only one test in that context)

eg, here's a re-writing of your spec the standard way:

```
let(:robin) { FactoryGirl.create(:robin) }
let(:absence) { FactoryGirl.create(:basic_absence, user: robin) }


context "with no public holidays" do
  it 'counts the absence day to be a day used' do
    expect(absence.days_used).to eq(1)
  end
end

context "with a public holiday for the absence" do
  before do
    FactoryGirl.create(:public_holiday, country: "England", account: robin.account)
  end
  it 'does not consider the absence day to be a day used' do
    expect(absence.days_used).to eq(0)
  end
end
```